I face issues trying to install Laravel on my machine
I am trying to run laravel project on my system which is giving me this error:

C:\Users\Owner>composer create-project --prefer-dist
laravel/laravel:^8.0 project-name
Creating a "laravel/laravel:8.0" project at "./project-name"
Cannot use laravel/laravel's latest version v8.0.0 as it requires php ^7.3 which is not satisfied by your platform.
In CreateProjectCommand.php line 421:
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extens
ions and Composer version.
create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository
REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository]
[--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts]
[--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs]
[--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT]
[--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
[--ask] [--] [ [ []]]

On running this command

composer global require laravel/installer

I get this error
C:\Users\Owner>composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 29 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing doctrine/inflector (2.0.10) into cache
    Failed to download illuminate/conditionable from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing illuminate/conditionable (v11.4.0) into cache
    Failed to download psr/simple-cache from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing psr/simple-cache (3.0.0) into cache
    Failed to download psr/container from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing psr/container (2.0.2) into cache
    Failed to download illuminate/contracts from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing illuminate/contracts (v11.4.0) into cache
    Failed to download illuminate/macroable from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing illuminate/macroable (v11.4.0) into cache
    Failed to download symfony/process from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing symfony/process (v7.0.4) into cache

In Process.php line 356:

  Unable to launch a new process.


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]


It does say The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing maybe enabling the zip extension in C:\xampp\php\php.ini (the one composer says it is using) might help
